# How to consume Azure Health Bot Skills by skill manifest/endpoint?

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-health-bot

I have created the scenarios in Azure HealthBot Management Portal and want to expose the skill to be consumed by other bot/rootbot. I have configured the skill exposure and got the skill manifest including the endpoint.When we are making the call to the api endpoint it is giving 404 error.

**Manifest:**

```
{
"$schema": "https://schemas.botframework.com/schemas/skills/v2.1/skill-manifest.json",
"$id": "testhealthbot",
"name": "testhealthbot",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "test",
"publisherName": "test",
"tags": [],
"endpoints": [
    {
        "name": "default",
        "protocol": "BotFrameworkV3",
        "description": "Production endpoint for HealthBot Skill testhealthbot",
        "endpointUrl": "https://bot-api-us.healthbot.microsoft.com/bot/dynabot/testhealthbot-hpmn88l/skill/consume",
        "msAppId": "3dc55673-cdd5-4e4d-8838-d51d2exxxxx"
    }
],
"activities": {
    "message": {
        "type": "message",
        "description": "Receives the user's' utterance and attempts to resolve it using the skill's LU models"
    }
}
}
```

can someone please guide me how to make api calls to the skill or to consume the skill in rootbot?

Answer (score 0):

To add your new Skill to your assistant/Bot you can use [botskills](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botskills) command line tool to automate the process of adding the Skill to your dispatch model and creating authentication connections where needed.
Run the following command from a command prompt within the directory of your assistant/Bot.

```
botskills connect --remoteManifest "https://<YOUR_SKILL_NAME>.azurewebsites.net/manifest/manifest-1.1.json" --cs --luisFolder "<PATH_TO_LU_FOLDER>"
```

see [adding skills](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/skills/handbook/add-skills-to-a-virtual-assistant/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a forwarding url with ngrok. And followed these steps,[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-connect-to-a-skill?tabs=v2x#test-your-root-bot-in-the-emulator)
still I was unable to connect to Azure Health Bot,I was getting error.

Adding the qna forum for reference
[microsoft_qna](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/846487/azure-health-bot.html?childToView=856363#comment-856363)

it would be very helpful, if someone would guide on adding azure health bot as a skill in rootBot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).